# Why would this code work on iPhone 5, 4 and 4s but not 5s?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have the below code for adding some `UIBarButton`s to my project. This works just fine on the following:

*All on iOS 7.1*

- Simulator iPhone Retina 3.5 inch;
- Simulator iPhone Retina 4 inch;
- Simulator iPhone Retina 4 inch (64 bit)
- Iphone 4
- iPhone 4s

I don't have an iPhone 5 device to test though.

It doesn't work on a new iPhone 5s. Whats different?

Here is the code:

```
    -(void)setupNavigationBar
{
    self.saveSearchButton =  [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [self.saveSearchButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Save Search"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.saveSearchButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Save Search Active"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted|UIControlStateSelected];
    [self.saveSearchButton addTarget:self action:@selector(saveSearchButtonpressed)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.saveSearchButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 23, 31)];

     self.changeLayutButton =  [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [self.changeLayutButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"View List"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.changeLayutButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"View Grid"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted|UIControlStateSelected];
    [self.changeLayutButton addTarget:self action:@selector(changeViewLayoutButtonPressed)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.changeLayutButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 23, 31)];

    self.sortByButton =  [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [self.sortByButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Sort By"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.sortByButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Sort By Active"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted|UIControlStateSelected];
    [self.sortByButton addTarget:self action:@selector(sortByButtonPressed)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.sortByButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 23, 31)];

    UIBarButtonItem *fixedItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace target:nil action:nil];
    fixedItem.width = 20;

    UIBarButtonItem *saveSearchButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:self.saveSearchButton];
    UIBarButtonItem *changeViewButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:self.changeLayutButton];
    UIBarButtonItem *sortByButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:self.sortByButton];


    NSArray *barbuttonitems = @[sortByButton, fixedItem, changeViewButton, fixedItem,saveSearchButton];

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = barbuttonitems;

    self.lastLayoutUsed = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"LastLayoutUsed"];

    if ([self.lastLayoutUsed isEqualToString:@"GridLayout"]){
        self.changeLayutButton.selected = YES;
        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.0 target:self selector:@selector(highlightButton:) userInfo:self.changeLayutButton repeats:NO];
    }
}
```

I've stepped through the code and all the properties are not nil and have valid values. I've checked all images are the correct side, too.

How would this work on every device on simulator and not an actual iPhone 5S?

Also, since the two phones (iPhone 4S and 5S) have the exact same screen width and iOS version I am really puzzled?

The buttons don't show up at all. No compiler warning and no console errors.

**UPDATE**

Tested the above code on a iPhone 5 and it works just fine. This leads be to believe it must be something to do with the 64bit of the iPhone 5S?

**UPDATE 2**

Removed all the code from the method and changed it to a very simple button like this:

```
         self.saveSearchButton =  [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[self.saveSearchButton setTitle:@"Save" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.saveSearchButton setTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    UIBarButtonItem *saveSearchButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:self.saveSearchButton];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = saveSearchButton;
```

This now doesn't work on any devices or simulators.

What am I doing wrong here?

**Update 3 - Solution!**

Right, so it was one simple thing that caused all this fuss. I declared my UIButtons as `weak` and not `strong` - I was under the impression that UI elements needed to be weak as they go off view so often?

I came to this answer with the help from the comments section.

This also does not explain why it works on iPhone 4S and iPhone 5 when declared as `weak`. It also worked on the 64 bit simulator declared as `weak`

Does this mean the 64bit simulator is to be used as a guide and actual testing must be done on the device as it seems the simulator is not accurate when it comes to `UIKit` testing?

I'd love to know more about this.

Comment: Please explain what part of this is not working. Does it display anything at all, any errors ?..

Comment: I'm sorry, should have been clear. The buttons don't show up at all. No compiler warnings no console warnings either.

Comment: "How would this work on every device on simulator and not an actual iPhone 5S?" The simulator is not perfect by any stretch of the imagination.

Comment: I'm starting to realise that more and more. Moving all UI tests to actual devices now.

Comment: If I had to guess it is related to the image naming. Try not using any spaces and make sure you're correct about case on the naming. As far as I know iOS is always case sensitive and MacOS isn't.

Comment: Thanks for the suggested. I removed all spacing and copied the image names from the asset catalog to make sure spelling was correct. Works on my iPhone 4S device. Not on my iPhone 5S. I really don't get why...

Comment: Another suggestion.. Are the images in the catalog as @2x? I'm not sure iPhone5S will look for the original sized versions of the images if it doesn't find the retina versions.

Comment: Yes, all images are in the X2 size in the catalog. Is there a way to debug this more than just stepping through the code? Thanks for your continued help - I appreciate it bud.

Comment: I managed to test on a iPhone 5 and the above code works. Is it maybe something to do with the 64 bit side of the iPhone 5S?

Comment: @Tander did you try to clean the project ? Maintain alt when cleaning so it clean the entire build folder

Comment: @Tander how do you conclude that its something to do with 64bit when you state it works on Simulator iPhone Retina 4 inch (64 bit) fine ? simulator may not be perfect but for most of the UIKit cases it works quite identical. try to use colors for buttons as a debug helper instead of images just to see if it shows up.

Comment: shot in the dark, but have you tried using doubles/floats wherever they are needed like here CGRectMake(0, 0, 23, 31) -> CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 23.0, 31.0) ?

Comment: I had not tried that. I did now and it made no difference. I got the buttons to work on other phones without images and just a text. Still does't work with iPhone5S. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: The problem is [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
This doesn't give you a instance of the UIButton object. Try changing it to a normal alloc+init. That should do the trick

Comment: Question: If that's the case - why would it work on the iPhone 4S device and not on iPhone 5S? I'll try it now.

Comment: @TotumusMaximus Your comment lead me to solving the issue. Can you add it as an answer and I will mark it as correct. I'll update the question as well on the solution. However it still doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Tander I've had these issues in the past with similar situations. They mention quite a few things about this method in the AppleDocs. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html. It's a very old function (since iOS2.0). They might have been way more forgiving to people who used this inappropriately on older devices and not so in the current one.

Comment: This is just a comment about `"Does this mean the 64bit simulator is to be used as a guide and actual testing must be done on the device as it seems the simulator is not accurate when it comes to UIKit testing?"` - You should always test on device and not rely on just the simulator, whilst the iOS simulator is a lot better then ones for Android devices you should never just develop and test against simulators.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was that `[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom]` doesn't leave an instance of the object as is stated in the Apple Docs. And the UIBarButton expects an instance of some sorts. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html

The solution as is stated in the AppleDocs is using the alloc+init construction to make a button.

> *buttonWithType:*
>
> "This method is a convenience constructor for creating button objects
> with specific configurations. If you subclass UIButton, this method
> does not return an instance of your subclass. If you want to create an
> instance of a specific subclass, you must alloc/init the button
> directly."

Comment: I totally agree with you the instance of the button object does need `buttonType:...` but this says to me that if this was missing it shouldn't work on any of the devices, this isn't specific to iPhone 5s devices this would be an iOS issue.

Comment: Apparantly Apple forgave programmers from using this construction in the past. But on newer devices like the iPhone5S they enforced a stricter way. Why and how? Only Apple knows. And do they let us know? Nope, at least not clearly and direct. We gotta deal with the way they run things and the only thing we can do is read the AppleDocs to the letter accurately.

Comment: The thing is it's not a device thing it is an iOS thing, I have always had to put this no matter what if I have ever missed it or done `[[UIButton alloc] init]` instead it never works no matter what device or iOS. By any chance do you have any documentation to say that this has been made more strict based on the device and not the iOS???

Comment: It's an assumption I made based on the question and experience I have. The solution of this problem was in any case the weak reference he had and the fact that buttonWithType: leaves no instance. This does mean the reference count doesn't go up at all and the button will be nil'ed as soon as the reference leaves the scope of the function it was declared in. However based on statements in this question this worked on older devices so this means something had to be changed in the workings of ARC (if he used it) or the initWithCustomView:. I can't find hard proof. So this is all assumptions.

Comment: +1 I recently faced this issue and particularly in iPhone5s it is not working but in all other devices it works i.e. ipad,ipod even iphone5, so I had to declare it as strong. @TotumusMaximus

Comment: `buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom` does NOT create a UIButton subclass. This answer is not correct here. See Brian Slick's answer below. The conclusive fix in this case should be to declare the UIButtons as `strong` as far as I can tell. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Another +1, had the same issues and not once, according not only UIButton. In all books was said that all views that not main, that are "subviews" or "child" views should be weak against strong "parent" view.

Answer (score 2):

@TotumusMaximus You have misunderstood what the documentation is saying. Note the first part:

> If you **subclass** UIButton...

What this means is that if you try to do `[MyAwesomeButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom]`, the object that will be created will be a UIButton instance, NOT a MyAwesomeButton instance. In order to get a MyAwesomeButton instance, then you would need to do `[[MyAwesomeButton alloc] init]`. There are no button subclasses involved in the OP's problem, so this portion of the documentation does not apply here.

Comment: I came to this same confused conclusion. I said to myself, `buttonWithType` does not create a subclass. Therefore, the voted for answer is incorrect. Does that mean the real solution is to give these UIButtons strong references and be done with it?

Answer (score 2):

If your properties are weak, and you directly assign a newly created object to them, then by the rules of ARC they *should* immediately be deallocated and set to nil, since nothing else holds a strong reference to them. The fact that is was working on other devices / simulators was an accident of implementation.

There is no real need to use weak properties for UI elements now that views are not unloaded under memory pressure conditions any more. If you do still want to use weak properties, the correct pattern to use is to create a local (strong) reference, add it to a superview, and *then* assign to the property - at this point the button will have an owning reference (the superview) so will not be removed by ARC:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:whatever];
[self.view addSubview:button];
self.button = button;
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. That helps my understanding. For simplicity I'll declare all UI properties as strong.